# Cell Fracture Issue | Some cells material is weird - need help! Blender v2.83

Tags: texturing, materials, motion-capture

Motion Tracking anomalies in Blender v2.83--My class project for animation VFX. Am attempting to crumble a building via an animated meteorite hit VFX, but after using Cell Fracture, the Image Texture used as the Material is acting weird.

If I delete the odd blocks, that leaves holes in the structure before the meteorite hits Cell Fracture.

I tried 'Flip Normals' but that didn't repair the anomaly.

Any/all help appreciated. Working in Blender v2.83 on my home desktop PC with Windows 10.

Need to finish project by this Sunday night 3/21!! Eek!!

Thanks to whomever is able to help :-)
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please [edit] your question so that all textual information is contained in the *text of your question*. Text that is in images becomes difficult to read, and is not searchable, thus becoming less useful to future visitors or users who would answer. As your question is currently written, the text alone provides no hints as to what your problem is, and therefore is not useful to providing an answer to your question or for a future visitor to find your question and an answer to theirs.

Comment: Timaroberts I have edited this question as I really need help. Thank you.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15924/timaroberts would you be able to re-open this question for me? I promise not to only put the texts in my pictures. Have changed my other question as well :-)

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Just some pointers, when asking, it's already assumed  help is needed :) And mentioning a deadline won't necessarily get a faster answer. The fastest way to an answer is a well asked, well formatted question. The more detailed you are with your research, and sharing what you know now, the better. See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for instance. :)

Comment: @Timaroberts Thank you for the pointers. I'm new to it all but will take these to heart and use these guidelines going forward.

Comment: Cell Facturing textured objects can do that.  It's because you are dealing with a host of new separate objects. Make a duplicate of the model to act as an outer covering.  That's done before any cell fracturing or physics are used. The duplicate won't be affected when the original is segmented. It's also expanded a whisker so there's no Z fighting (shimmering).  The result is no fracture cracks and the original texture returned.
cont...

Comment: ...cont from previous - At frame 1 the duplicate is visible and optionally, the fractured version invisible. At the impact frame or thereabouts, the reverse is the case - duplicate invisible and fractured version visible.  (the eye and camera icons in the Outliner will do that)

Comment: A quick & dirty demo below... Your bursting wall or section would obviously be different to the clip but note how the texture and building is fine before the blowout.  The cell fracture murdered the texture when set up but it's not
visible so it doesn't matter.  The clip -

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkhCKZLZs_Pg2ofySayjHmaoRBD?e=8mIu2J

Comment: Thank you Edgel3D - got it and is working now :D

Comment: That's good to hear,  hope you get a good mark for that! :)